# C# Why is SelectedNode.Tag null?

Tags: c#, null, treeview, selecteditem

I use TreeView in my C# project (Windows Forms) and I have a problem (obviously :P). I fill my TreeView like this:

```
void RefreshTreeView()
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < categories.Count ; ++i)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(categories[i].name);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < categories[i].questions.Count ; ++j)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add("Pytanie nr " + categories[i].questions[j].number.ToString()
                + " za " + categories[i].questions[j].points.ToString() + " pkt. ["
                + (categories[i].questions[j].used ? "Przeczytane" : "Nieprzeczytane") + "]");
            treeView1.Nodes[i].Tag = categories[i].questions[j];   // A
        }
    }
}
```

In line marked "A" above I attach a Question object to Node's Tag. And it seems to work as later on in the program I can retrieve my Question object like this:

```
((Question)treeView1.Nodes[0].Tag).number
```

But I want to get the currently selected Node's Tag. Which I try to do like this:
    `((Question)treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag).number`
But it doesn't work (Tag is null). What am I doing wrong? And how to get the currently selected Node's Tag?

Comment: I think that it returns null because it IS null. There is something else in you program that either sets it to null or fails to set it to the expected value. Or somewhere you are accessing an object different from what you intend to access. In short `SelectedNode` returns a `TreeNode` object just like `Nodes[x]` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`treeView1.Nodes[i].Tag` is the tag of the parent node.

You probably want to set the tag of the child node, which is `treeView1.Nodes[i].Node[j].Tag`